# Remove all Non-characters, except the numbers, latin letter and Cyrillic letter in python

Tags: python

I want to remove all the punctuation, special letters like `"ū","ú","ǔ","ù","ǖ","ǘ","ǚ","ǜ","ü","û"`,  `▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬◄` and any other chars chars, except the `numbers, latin letters and cyrillic` .
the input string is encoded as `utf-8`
How to realize this ?

Comment: What do you mean by removing "special letters" but not "latin letters"? Letters like "ú" are latin.

Comment: If you want just to remove accents, then see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string#518232 However, keep in mind that "latin letters" are not only the 26 letters of English alphabet. There are still all cases like the Ĳ digraph (from Dutch) or Ł letter (from Polish). Same applies to Cyrillic script, its a lot more than just Russian alphabet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from string import ascii_letters, digits, whitespace

cyrillic_letters = u"абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"


def strip(text):
    allowed_chars = cyrillic_letters + ascii_letters + digits + whitespace
    print(allowed_chars)
    return "".join([c for c in text if c in allowed_chars])
```

**edit:** Not familiar with the Cyrillic alphabet but this is how I managed to strip characters except as you specified Cyrillic-letters, latin-letters, non-numbers and (I added this one) whitespace from a string.